# How can I create monthly repeating tasks in Flutter/Firebase?

Tags: android, database, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently working on a finance app, where the user can create many transactions.

To make the user's job a little easier, I want to add transactions that repeat themselves every month.
I use Flutter/Firebase for the app and if a user has a Netflix subscription for example, they have to pay money for it every month.
However, I want the app to add to the Firebase database every month this transaction, without the user having to do anything.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Check the current date, check if the event should happen at the moment, if it does, make it happen.

Comment: Maybe you should try Firebase cloud Functions.